# Website in multiple Language

Tags: multi-language, translation

I want to make Sit in Wordpress in which I want to make content in ENglish and Gujrati Language . WHen Admin create a Page in English at that time Admin want to create content with Gujarati Language. Then what I need to do? Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Well use translation plugin (multilingual Plugins)to create page in english and gujrati.

**There are a few basic types of multilingual Plugins:**

**1**   Manage multilingual posts in one post per language (e.g. WPML - paid, xili-language, Polylang or Bogo). Translations are then linked together, indicating that one page is the translation of another.

**2**  Store all languages alternatives for each post in the same post (e.g. qTranslate).

**3**   Manage translations on the generated page instead of using a post context (e.g. Transposh and Global Translator)

**4**   Plugins that direct you to external translation services (e.g. Google AJAX Translation)

**5**  Plugins like Multisite Language Switcher and the newcomer Multilingual Press link together separate WordPress network (multisite) installations for each language by pinging back and forth.